# How can I get a resource dynamically in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I am working on an Android application and I have multiple string arrays defined in my `strings.xml` file. In my app, I have an input box where the user can type a specific keyword, and based on that keyword, I want to retrieve the corresponding string array dynamically.

For instance, let's say I have the following arrays defined in my `strings.xml` file:

```xml
<string-array name="fruit">
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Orange</item>
    <item>Banana</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="colors">
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
</string-array>
```

Now, if the user types "fruit" in the input box, I want to fetch the array named fruit, and if the user types "colors", I want to retrieve the array named colors. How can I achieve this dynamically in my Android application?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.